# In Python, how to get a localized timestamp with only the datetime package?

Tags: python, datetime, epoch, python-datetime

I have a unix timestamp in seconds (such as `1294778181`) that I can convert to UTC using

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_timestamp)
```

Problem is, I would like to get the corresponding time in `'US/Eastern'` (considering any DST) and I cannot use `pytz` and other utilities.

Only `datetime` is available to me.

Is that possible?
Thanks!

Comment: You could write your own function that would add/subtract timedelta

Comment: yeah I would like to avoid that, because then you need to keep track of the right offset right?

Comment: Yah, but I can't think of another way :/ You could always write your own pytz :D https://github.com/newvem/pytz/tree/master/pytz

Comment: can you write an answer based on your timedelta idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest, but not supersmart solution is using timedelta

```
import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

US/Eastern is 5 hours behind UTC, so let's just create thouse five hours as a timedelta object and make it negative, so that when reading back our code we can see that the offset is -5 and that there's no magic to deciding when to add and when to subtract timezone offset

```
>>> eastern_offset = -(datetime.timedelta(hours=5))
>>> eastern = now + eastern_offset
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 26, 20, 7, 12, 375841)
>>> eastern
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 26, 15, 7, 12, 375841)
```

If we wanted to fix DST, we'd run the datetime through smoething like this (not entirely accurate, timezones are not my expertise (googling a bit now it changes each year, yuck))

```
if now.month > 2 and now.month < 12:
    if (now.month == 3 and now.day > 12) or (now.month == 11 and now.day < 5):
        eastern.offset(datetime.timedelta(hours=5))
```

You could go even into more detail, add hours, find out how exactly it changes each year... I'm not going to go through all that :)

Comment: great but does this take into account DST?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. it could be fixed by having if conditions applying another hour offset when the datetime's date without a year is between two another datetimes

Comment: @Noobie I edited my answer with a broad idea of how to do DST, but it's rather complicated if you want it to be always accurate. It's why we have pytz